# Flexi-grid sorting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, flexigrid

I am using Flexigrid.js in a MVC4 application.  Everything works great but I cannot get it to sort.  It should hit the controller code when you click on a header but it does not.  Anyone had this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood your question correctly,Here is few samples you can go through.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30588/ASP-NET-MVC-Flexigrid-sample

http://www.kenthouse.com/blog/2009/07/fun-with-flexigrids/